# Automapper - Add to List conditionally

Tags: c#, automapper

The situation is -

```
public class One
{
    public string S1 { get;set; }
    public string S2 { get;set; }
    public string S3 { get;set; }
    public string S4 { get;set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public List<string> List1 { get;set; }
}
```

Now what I want is to populate the list inside `Two` with the non-null property values of `One`.

Is there anyway / work-around to achieve this using `AutoMapper` ?

Comment: You can use custom value resolver - https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers

Comment: I'll let you know, if this works.And accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can create your own custom value resolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<One, List<string>>
{
    protected override List<string> ResolveCore(One source)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        //your logic
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.S1))
            result.Add(source.S1);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.S2))
            result.Add(source.S2);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.S3))
            result.Add(source.S3);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.S4))
            result.Add(source.S4);

        return result;
    }
}
```

*Mapping configuration:*

```
Mapper.CreateMap<One, Two>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.List1, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

In this way you are able to configure mappings for specific properties

Comment: Well that helped. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only mapping you want to do between the classes, you can use a custom type converter: this then takes complete charge of the mapping between the objects.

```
public class OneTwoTypeResolver : TypeConverter<One, Two>
{
    protected override Two ConvertCore(One source)
    {
        Two two = new Two {List1 = new List<string>()};

        if (source.S1 != null)
            two.List1.Add(source.S1);

        if (source.S2 != null)
            two.List1.Add(source.S2);

        if (source.S3 != null)
            two.List1.Add(source.S3);

        if (source.S4 != null)
            two.List1.Add(source.S4);

        return two;
    }
}
```

You tell AutoMapper to use this class when mapping between the classes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<One, Two>().ConvertUsing<OneTwoTypeResolver>();
```

Then this test will pass:

```
public void Test()
{
    One one = new One {S2 = "OneTwoThreeFour"};
    Two two = Mapper.Map<One, Two>(one);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, two.List1.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("OneTwoThreeFour", two.List1.Single());
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `This is straightforward with a custom type converter` not with `resolver`

Comment: This helps too.Thanks mate